# How can I produce a consistent byte signature within C++ functions?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, assembly, 64-bit, obfuscation

I would like to embed a consistent byte signature inside a C++ function. The purpose of such a signature is to **act as a beacon** and **provide space** for the insertion/moving of instructions for binary obfuscation. For example. a tool might search the resulting binary for the signature and then replace it with randomly generated code blocks that effectively do nothing, resulting in somewhat polymorphic code. This requires that the signature must be directly in line with the code and the compiler must consider it to be part of the function.

In 32-bit Visual C++, this can easily be done using inline assembly:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello";
    Sleep(1);

    _asm
    {
        _EMIT 0x04
        _EMIT 0x05
        _EMIT 0x06
        _EMIT 0x07
        _EMIT 0x08
        _EMIT 0x09
    }

    cout << " world" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However I am looking for a method which will also work for 64-bit binaries built by Visual C++.

### Things I've considered or tried

#### Solution: just use Visual Studio's inline assembly feature

- Problem: does not support x64

#### Solution: write the signature as an MASM function (in a .asm file)

- Problem: impossible to inline these functions

#### Solution: use an inline C++ function as the signature

- Problem: even __forceinline doesn't guarantee that the function will be inlined
- While testing this, the compiler didn't actually inline the function even once
- Even if it was inlined, it might compile to use different registers per expansion

#### Solution: Macro that expands to a bunch of statements

- Problem: compiler optimization breaks apart the instructions bundled in these macros
- Problem: compiler still uses different registers for each instance of the macro

Note that the signature scanning algorithm can be as sophisticated as needed (it can use a mask, it can scan only the code sections, etc as long as the signature consistently follows some pattern). Also, I'm looking for a solution that can be used with production code ie. disabling optimizations across the project is not OK.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably should migrate question to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to inline code, why not just utilize a function call as the "signature"? If the function call requires a fixup, the linker will advertise the location of the instruction in the fixup table so you can just read it from there as needed instead of searching.

Comment: That would provide a consistent signature, yes, but 5 bytes isn't a whole lot of space to work with. I don't believe it would be possible to expand those 5 bytes after linking either - even if you fixed up all the relocations and stuff you would still break things like short jumps.